# One Way to Grab both text and percentages regex python

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
Bbc (57%); Grameen (54%); Cninsure (66%) Mn-Public-Radio-Intl
```

I'd like to obtain:

```
[BBC World Service, 57], [Grameen Bank, 54], [Cninsure Inc., 66], [Mn-Public-Radio-Intl, np.nan]
```

I was using this pattern `.+?(?=\()`
But it is inadequate becaause `Mn-Public-Radio-Intl` doesn't have a parantheses. 
Would appreciate help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the parenthesis optional; you'll get an empty string:

```
re.findall(r'(\b[\w -]+\b)(?:\s+\((\d+)%\))?', inputtext)
```

Demo:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(\b[\w -]+\b)(?:\s+\((\d+)%\))?', inputtext)
[('Bbc', '57'), ('Grameen', '54'), ('Cninsure', '66'), ('Mn-Public-Radio-Intl', '')]
```

To get integers or `float('nan')` you can post process this:

```
import numpy as np

[(name, int(perc) if perc else np.nan)
 for name, perc in re.findall(r'(\b[\w -]+\b)(?:\s+\((\d+)%\))?', inputtext)]
```

which then gives:

```
>>> [(name, int(perc) if perc else np.nan)
...  for name, perc in re.findall(r'(\b[\w -]+\b)(?:\s+\((\d+)%\))?', inputtext)]
[('Bbc', 57), ('Grameen', 54), ('Cninsure', 66), ('Mn-Public-Radio-Intl', nan)]
```

Comment: I apologize greatly. Could you look at my question again? I realize oversimplifying the names makes it easier than it is because you can assume that the words are one word only.

Comment: I get this: [('Bbc', ''),
 ('World', ''),
 ('Service', ''),
 ('Television', ''),
 ('Ltd', ' (57%)'),
 ('Grameen', ''),
 ('Bank', ' (54%)'),
 ('Cninsure', ''),
 ('Inc', ' (66%)'),
 ('Mn-Public-Radio-Intl', '')]

Comment: why can't i put a space in [\w- ]+ ? I keep getting bad character range.

Comment: @user3314418: You can, but it *before* the `-`. May as well make it `\S` then.

Comment: ok great. i think that solved the problem of multiple words if we put in \s. what do u think?

Comment: @user3314418: I've adjusted the pattern to allow for spaces in the text.